# Mysql retrieve orders from last year in the same month as today

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table orders and I would like to make a request to retrieve all orders from the month of last year to the same month as now. Example: we are in November, I would like to recover all the orders of the month of November 2017.

I try something like that but it does not work:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM ps_orders o
   WHERE YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
   AND MONTH(o.date_add) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to subtract the month. It should be `MONTH(NOW())` to get the same month results from the previous year.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ps_orders o
WHERE YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  AND MONTH(o.date_add) = MONTH(NOW()) -- same as current month
```

Comment: Yeah its work :) I see my mistake indeed ... thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing this with date ranges:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ps_orders o
WHERE o.date_add >= (curdate() - interval (day - 1) day) - interval 12 month AND
      o.date_add >= (curdate() - interval (day - 1) day) - interval 11 month ;
```

When you use functions such as `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` the optimizer will not take full advantage of an available index on `date_add`.  However, this version can use an appropriate index.